# Is there a shorter way to extract hour from timestamp stored as integer than EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime))?

Tags: google-bigquery

As in topic. While using standard-sql is there a shorter way to extract hour (or other dateparts) from timestamp stored as integer than EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime))?

Comment: if you find it long, place in a view. And reference the view in the main query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) in such cases when you feel something should have shorter way to be expressed

See example below

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION HOUR(time INT64)
RETURNS INT64 AS (
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(time))
);

SELECT 
  HOUR(visitStartTime) as `shorertWay`, 
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime)) as `longerWay`
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`
LIMIT 10
```

So, now instead of

```sql
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime))
```

you can use

```sql
HOUR(visitStartTime)
```